# Create a loop for timeout UDP Connection

Tags: python, sockets, udp

Using this sample code and methods how would someone go about implementing a 5 second timeout if the server does not respond and stop trying to connect after 10 times? It would be a loop of some sort but I am not sure how it would be implemented and where exactly it would be placed in the client code.

Client Code:

```
import socket

 

msgFromClient       = "Hello UDP Server"

bytesToSend         = str.encode(msgFromClient)

serverAddressPort   = ("127.0.0.1", 20001)

bufferSize          = 1024

 

# Create a UDP socket at client side

UDPClientSocket = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

 

# Send to server using created UDP socket

UDPClientSocket.sendto(bytesToSend, serverAddressPort)

 

msgFromServer = UDPClientSocket.recvfrom(bufferSize)

 

msg = "Message from Server {}".format(msgFromServer[0])

print(msg)
```

Server Code:

```
import socket

 

localIP     = "127.0.0.1"

localPort   = 20001

bufferSize  = 1024

 

msgFromServer       = "Hello UDP Client"

bytesToSend         = str.encode(msgFromServer)

 

# Create a datagram socket

UDPServerSocket = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

 

# Bind to address and ip

UDPServerSocket.bind((localIP, localPort))

 

print("UDP server up and listening")

 

# Listen for incoming datagrams

while(True):

    bytesAddressPair = UDPServerSocket.recvfrom(bufferSize)

    message = bytesAddressPair[0]

    address = bytesAddressPair[1]

    clientMsg = "Message from Client:{}".format(message)
    clientIP  = "Client IP Address:{}".format(address)
    
    print(clientMsg)
    print(clientIP)

   

    # Sending a reply to client

    UDPServerSocket.sendto(bytesToSend, address)
```

Answer (score 0):

UDP is a connectionless protocol, you might want to use TCP instead. But, if you still want to implement some kind of timeout mechanism, the most straightforward way to achieve it could be by importing time module, setting the client UDP socket as non-blocking with `UDPClientSocket.setblocking(0)` and then continuously read from socket in a while loop, until you receive data, while measuring time with `time.time()`, which returns time in seconds since the epoch.

Comment: could you please show howe that would look with UDP in my code if possible?

Comment: Yes, I can, but I won't. Please, show some effort in the code before stepping to the next answer.

Comment: Dont worry I figured it out